# Image source to writeablebitmap in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, writeablebitmap

I'm working on windows phone 8.1 application. I have different pictures locally in app and displaying those pictures in list view.  Now select one picture id and pass it to detail screen, where I have to save that file .

My detail.Xaml screen contain image control named as Imaged.
I got image on detail page and press image save button. I'm using this Sample app https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Save-Edited-Picture-16d910c4/sourcecode?fileId=119937&pathId=946309183  "Sample"

My detail page Code is here.

```
         string tempimg; 
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
            var imagePath = e.Parameter as string;
            imaged.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

            tempimg = imagePath;

    }
```

My SaveImage button code is here.

```
   if (tempimg == null)
            return;

       // WriteableBitmap abc = new WriteableBitmap(400, 400);

        string filename = "Image-" + DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + ".jpeg";
       // await SaveWriteableBitmapAsJpeg(img, filename);
```

> Blockquote

**await SaveWriteableBitmapAsJpeg(tempimg, filename);**

```
    private static async Task SaveWriteableBitmapAsJpeg(WriteableBitmap bmp, string fileName)
    {
        // Create file in Pictures library and write jpeg to it
        var outputFile = await KnownFolders.CameraRoll.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (var writeStream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            await EncodeWriteableBitmap(bmp, writeStream, BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId);
        }
    }

    private static async Task EncodeWriteableBitmap(WriteableBitmap bmp, IRandomAccessStream writeStream, Guid encoderId)
    {
        // Copy buffer to pixels
        byte[] pixels;
        using (var stream = bmp.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
        {
            pixels = new byte[(uint)stream.Length];
            await stream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
        }

        // Encode pixels into stream
        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(encoderId, writeStream);
        encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
           (uint)bmp.PixelWidth, (uint)bmp.PixelHeight,
           96, 96, pixels);
        await encoder.FlushAsync();
    }
```

My this function "await SaveWriteableBitmapAsJpeg(tempimg, filename);"  creates a problem. I just have the image source while that require the writeablebitmap.    I just want to save image and not able to proceed from here. let me know the exact solution or problem.